# Webcam not working with wine

Tags: wine, webcam

I'm not able to make a webcam work with wine-1.7.30
(the webcam is the integrated webcam in my pc and works fine with other applications )

I found some suggestions but they don't seem to work. Has anyone managed to fix this bug?

Comment: Can you give some more details about the version of Ubuntu that you are running and the specific hardware that you are using?

Comment: My system is 64 Linux Mint Tricia 19.3 with desktop env MATE. which is based on ubuntu, I believe. ? @Gordster